# Plotting fitted response vs observed response

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a model which has been created like this

```
cube_model <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3), data = d.r.data)
```

I have been using `ggplot` methods like `geom_point` to plot datapoints and `geom_smooth` to plot the regression line. Now the question i am trying to solve is to plot `fitted` data vs `observed` .. How would i do that? I think i am just unfamiliar with `R` so not sure what to use here.

--

EDIT

I ended up doing this

```
predicted <- predict(cube_model)
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(x, predicted))
```

Is this correct approach?

Comment: why can't you just plot your predicted vs y, eg. ```ggplot(data.frame(observed=y,predicted=predicted)) + geom_point(aes(x=observed,y=predicted))```

Comment: or did i get your question wrong?

Comment: You may be right. I am not sure how to use R so was just trying to find a way to do so. Most of the articles that I found online didn't talk about ggplot library

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use the `predict` function to generate the fitted values. You can then add them back to your data.

```
d.r.data$fit <- predict(cube_model)
```

If you want to plot the predicted values vs the actual values, you can use something like the following.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d.r.data) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = fit, y = y))
```

Comment: Check my response above. I have updated the code (which makes sense to me). is it okay?

Comment: Predict generates a single vector of predicted values. You would need to add your predicted values back to your data to generate the plot you want.

Comment: okay, so in that case how would i generate the plot? could you please update the answer with the command to plot it as well?